# Python Issue with class variables pointing to functions

Tags: python, pandas, function, object

I want to use objects to handle reading various types of input data. The final implementation will be much more complicated and basically the parent class will define some methods and just use read_func and the subclasses can handle the implementation of read_func, probably pointing to something like pd.read_excel or maybe adding on a few data cleaning steps. But I'm getting this odd error, here's a small reproducible example:

test.py:

```
import pandas as pd
class test:
  read_func = pd.read_excel
print(pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")) # prints the excel fine
print(test().read_func) # prints <bound method read_excel of <__main__.test object at 0x104cebc70>>
print(test().read_func("test.xlsx")) # throws error
```

The error trace looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my/file/path/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    test().read_func("test.xlsx")
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1376, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1250, in inspect_excel_format
    with get_handle(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 670, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 427, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class '__main__.test'>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `read_excel` is a function that takes one argument. Any `function`-valued class attribute, though, will be treated as an instance method, and must be ready to accept an instance of the class as its first argument (which `pd.read_excel` is not).

Comment: (That's why instance methods are always defined with a first parameter named `self`: `test().read_func("...")` is really equivalent to `test.read_func(test(), "...")`.)

Comment: hmm that makes sense, does that mean there's no way to keep a pointer to a function like you would any other variable? Like for a string I can reference instance.string_value and that will just represent a string, no object overhead at all and it can be used everywhere a normal string could be used. Is there no way to pass around a pointer to a function in the same way by referencing instance.func?

Comment: You can, but it can't be a *class* attribute. This is due to the descriptor protocol. (Since `function` implements the `__get__` method, `test().read_func` does not return a reference to the function, but rather the result of `test().read_func.__get__` (which is a `method` instance that gets called, and calls the underlying function with `test()` as the first argument).

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
class test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.read_func = pd.read_excel
print(pd.read_excel("test.xlsx"))
print(test().read_func)
print(test().read_func("test.xlsx"))
```